# Несколько HttpClient в одном приложении

Tags: javascript, angular, httpclient

У меня в приложении есть интерцептор, который добавляет разные префиксы к URL в зависимости от environment (ключ `-c` при сборке)

```
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const apiReq = req.clone({url: `${this.baseUri}${req.url}`});
    return next.handle(apiReq);
  }
```

Провайдер:

```
{provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useFactory: () => new BaseUriInterceptor(environment.backendUri), multi: true},
```

Сейчас появилась необходимость делать запросы на другой бекенд.
Как получить ещё один HttpClient без интерцепторов, прописанных в корневом модуле?

Какие существуют best-practice по поводу существования нескольких HttpClient в одном приложении?

Comment: > `Как получить ещё один HttpClient ` - никак. > `Какие существуют best-practice по поводу существования нескольких HttpClient в одном приложении` - их не существует :D > `появилась необходимость делать запросы на другой бекенд` - проксируй запросы через бек (api-gateway)

Comment: Ну, технически я ведь могу запилить свой сервис, не используя HttpClient

Comment: Я надеялся, что можно навешивать интерцепторы не глобально, а например, в рамках одного модуля.

Comment: нет, перехватичики провайдятся только в руте, и не используй `useFactory`, ты же можешь спокойно использовать `environment.backendUri` в классе, а провайдить через `useClass`

Comment: Мне показалось, что явная зависимость в конструкторе выглядит лучше, чем импорт

Comment: Не могли бы вы оформить ответ? Негативный ответ - тоже ответ)

Comment: представь что тебе нужно в перехватчик инжектнуть несколько сервисов - `Store` редаксовсий, какой-то `UsersService` и бла-бла... тогда начнутся танцы

Comment: не, я ж тебе ничем не помог ))

Comment: Помог! С этим знанием я теперь вынесу эту часть в отдельный SPA или запилю сторонний client(раскурив, нужны ли тут аналоги $scope.$apply) =) А так - продолжил бы искать способ разделить перехватчики.

Comment: я не самый лучший бекендщик, но я б на твоем месте такую логику вынес на бек и пускай клиент останется с минимальным "знанием"

Comment: Не, на основном беке прокси собирать не вариант - по сути эти 2 бекенда - это махровый легаси(основной php5.2) и свежие модули на symfony под php7.3 =) Слать запросы в php5.2 ой как не хочется)

Comment: )) как вариант можно иметь 2 перехватчика под 2 бекенда и просто делать проверку что например `url.includes('firstBackendUrl')` и также во втором, если `!includes` - то просто возвращаешь реквест дальше в поток, типа `if (!req.url.includes(...)) return next.handle(..)`. С одной стороны костыль, с другой если решает конкретную проблему - то почему бы и нет + у тебя в энвайронмете есть уже `backendUri`

Comment: А можно роутить их прямо в интерцепторе) Это надо подумать. Благодарю)

Comment: можно, но не "роутить". angular проверяет что токен `HTTP_INTERCEPTORS` ссылается на какие-то классы, если да - то просто через `reduce` вызывает `interceptorInstance.intercept`, а делать в `intercept` ты можешь все что душа позволит

Comment: Может быть поможет это: http://www.learn-angular.fr/how-can-we-have-multiple-instances-of-httpclient-instance-with-angular/ Тут как раз 2 клиента с разным набором интерсепторов.